# UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage always present

Tags: ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

this code is bugging me as I took this from the apple documentation for using the UIImagePickerController. The section where you check if the image was edited using the “if (editedImage)” always comes out true. This is so (as according to people on this site) as UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage will always have data even if image was not edited, when the picker is set to editing YES. The problem is how can we know which was selected if both (UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage and UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) turns out to be non-nil?

I looked thru many tutorials and many other question on here and Google. But it comes back to the same fact the logic of the code gets you the edited image 100% even if you have not edited it.

I tested this code and other codes that had been given in other questions but the problems always remains the same I can’t tell which one is the one the user want to use. It would really help if the dictionary had a BOOL value to know.

While testing my app if I choose a photo from the album or take a new one I am taken to the edit screen where I can cancel or accept and resize/crop the image. And pressing accept gets me the edited image all the time even if I have not touched the image.

Here is the code from apple documentation API for the image picker.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
        UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

        // Handle a still image capture
        if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
            == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

            editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                       UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
            originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                         UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            if (editedImage) {
                imageToSave = editedImage;
            } else {
                imageToSave = originalImage;
            }
        }
      // work with image or save and exit modal. 
    }
```

Comment: This is the way it should work as you have set the editing mode of UIImagePickerController to true it automatically scales the image and crop it even if you do not touch the image it only use the image which is currently visible in square (white bordered). So you always get edited image property assigned or say not null

Comment: @Wolvorin So I take it that there is just no way to know to use the original over the edited one. :( then I guess to give the user the choice I need to turn off editing and let the user decide in a new view controller how they want the app background to be. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is the one solution, and I think this is the only solution for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

closing question as per Wolvorin's answer:

This is the way it should work as you have set the editing mode of UIImagePickerController to true it automatically scales the image and crop it even if you do not touch the image it only use the image which is currently visible in square (white bordered). So you always get edited image property assigned or say not null – Wolvorin Jan 30 at 8:32